# extract specific hour from time stamp in given column

Tags: r, string, datetime, timestamp, data-manipulation

```
timestamp
2001-06-12 14:05:00
2001-08-12 15:06:00
2001-09-11 18:05:00
2001-06-22 14:05:00
2001-06-02 14:05:00
2001-06-12 18:05:00
2001-06-12 14:05:00
2001-06-12 11:11:00
2001-06-12 18:59:00
```

I have to find the frequency of the `18:00 hour` (18:00:00 to 18:59:59) from the above time stamp.

The output should be like below:

```
Output      18th_hour      
Frequency   3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the hour component of timestamp and count the occurrence of `"18"`th hour.

In base R we can do as

```
sum(format(as.POSIXct(df$timestamp), "%H") == "18")
#[1] 3
```

---

Similar using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
sum(hour(ymd_hms(df$timestamp)) == 18)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
5L), .Label = c("2001-06-02 14:05:00", "2001-06-12 11:11:00", 
"2001-06-12 14:05:00", "2001-06-12 18:05:00", "2001-06-12 18:59:00", 
"2001-06-22 14:05:00", "2001-08-12 15:06:00", "2001-09-11 18:05:00"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `anytime` to convert the 'timestamp' column to Datetime, extract the `hour` and get the `sum` of elements that are 18

```
library(anytime)
sum(hour(anytime(df$timestamp)) == 18)
#[1] 3
```

---

Or with `strptime` from `base R`

```
sum(strptime(df$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")$hour == 18)
```

---

Or using a regex option

```
sum(grepl(" 18", df$timestamp))
#[1] 3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = c("2001-06-12 14:05:00", "2001-08-12 15:06:00", 
"2001-09-11 18:05:00", "2001-06-22 14:05:00", "2001-06-02 14:05:00", 
"2001-06-12 18:05:00", "2001-06-12 14:05:00", "2001-06-12 11:11:00", 
"2001-06-12 18:59:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```